# Cannot get the data via my scripts but the data is available when I "inspect"

Tags: python, web-scraping

When I inspect "https://dse.bigexam.hk/en/ssp?p=1&band=1&order=name&asc=1" I can find the data I want.  For examples the total pages "Showing schools 1 to 10 of 143." can be found.  However, I got no data from my scripts.  Anyone can help?  Thanks.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def makeSoup(url):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

url = "https://dse.bigexam.hk/en/ssp?p=1&band=1&order=name&asc=1"
soup = makeSoup(url)
pages = soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'col-sm'})
print(pages)
```

Comment: In such cases I would assume that the content is provided via JavaScript that BeautifulSoup can not retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

That's because it's loaded using Ajax/javascript. Requests library doesn't handle that, you'll need to use something that can execute these scripts and get the dom.

you can try selenium